# Displaying an iTunes webpage in Swift

Tags: swift, webkit, itunes

I would like to display an iTunes page in my app. 
Eg: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evil-cogs/id1292156349?mt=8

A regular webpage displays fine, but when I pass the above link to WebKit View, nothing happens, it is just a white page.

Comment: Are you testing on a real iOS device or in the simulator? Try it on a real device.

Comment: You should also consider using `SKStoreProductViewController`.